How to use the condition field in dependencies with an array of objects in a helm chart with multiple subcharts
I would like to control the installation of subcharts using the conditions field in the parent chart. According to the docs,

The condition field holds one or more YAML paths (delimited by commas). If this path exists in the top parent's values and resolves to a boolean value, the chart will be enabled or disabled based on that boolean value.

I tried to create a values.schema.yaml with the following content:
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "global": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "deploy": {
          "description": "Controls which subcharts (not) to deploy. Provide a separate values file to enable them.",
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "description": "Name of the subchart",
                "type": "string"
              },
              "enabled": {
                "description": "Whether to install the subchart or not",
                "type": "boolean"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

This should enable me to create an arbitrary number of deploy objects in my parent chart's global section of the values.yaml file:
  deploy:
  - name: "subchart01"
    enabled: false
  - name: "subchart02"
    enabled: true

My question is: How can I use this in the condition field of the Chart.yaml of the parent chart?
dependencies:
- name: subchart01
  version: 0.1.0
  repository: "file://charts/subchart01"
  condition: global.deploy. ??? .enabled

If you have another suggestion how to achieve something similar, maybe with another schema, I am happy to hear it.

That particular syntax doesn't support arrays in the Helm values.  Your deploy: field must be a YAML mapping, like
global:
  deploy:
    subchart01:
      enabled: false
    subchart02:
      enabled: true

and then the dependencies in requirements.yaml or Chart.yaml can say
dependencies:
- name: subchart01
  condition: global.deploy.subchart01.enabled

(For all that Kubernetes manifests routinely use arrays of objects with name: keys, that structure doesn't have much direct support in Helm.)

(It also seems like you're trying to build an "umbrella" chart, combining together multiple independent Helm charts into a single installable release.  I've had a number of practical problems with using these, ranging from Helm flattening dependencies to conflicts between named templates to charts written to only work within the umbrella framework.  I might consider a higher-level tool like Helmfile that can manage multiple helm installs as an alternative.)

I'm using the approach mentioned in your answer at the moment, this forces me to explicitly declare the subchart names in the values.schema.json though. I was looking for a solution where this is not required.

This would be required anyways, though; in your existing schema I'm guessing you'd need to list out the valid values for name:?  (Is deploy: [{name: anything, enabled: true}] valid if anything isn't a known subchart?)

With the schema specified in my question, yes it is possible to have arbitrary names for subcharts. Using that approach would save from having to define the subcharts' names in the schema.
